# Call multiple methods in mongosoft soap server in yii2

Tags: php, soap, yii2, soapserver

Hi all please help me to do this

I create a controller in yii2 for soap server. I am using mongosoft soap server for this. I can call a sing function using this  and my requirement is to call multiple method call using same controller.

Here below i given the code in controller.

```
class AController extends Controller {
    public function actions()
    {
        return [

            'hello' => 'mongosoft\soapserver\Action',
         ];

     }

/**
 * @param string $name
 * @return string
 * @soap
 */
    public function hello($code)
    {
    // code here
    }
    public function thanks($code,$msg)
    {
    // code here
    }
}
```

In the above I need to call another function with new parameters.

> how to call (thanks function ) in the action.

Comment: is any option for this problem.?

Answer (score 0):

You still need only one action (which is `hello` here). Calling `thanks()` will be specified in the SOAP body like

```
<soapenv:Envelope ... >
   ...
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xyz:thanks>
         <code xsi:type="xsd:string">some_code</code>
         <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">some message</msg>
      </xyz:thanks>
   </soapenv:Body>
   ...
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know is a really old post, but it was my problem too, so I solved it by adding comments above the method I want to include in the service:

```
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @return string
 * @soap
 */
public function thanks($code,$msg)
{
    return $msg;
}
```